Why an empty object can the type asserted to anything?
Seems like it shouldn't be allowed...
let wow = {} as boolean //No errors O.O
let wow2 = {} as [] //No errors O.O
let wow3 = {} as Function //No errors O.O
let wow4 = {} as number //No errors O.O
let wow5 = {} as string //No errors O.O
let wow6 = {} as symbol //No errors O.O


• The premise is false here, you can't write {} as null or {} as undefined. • Do you know how type assertions work? They allow downcasting (narrowing). If you already know this, please [edit] the question to indicate that you're not asking why you can unsafely narrow with type assertions.  • Do you know what the type of {} is in TypeScript? It's the "empty object type" which is compatible with everything except null and undefined.   IF you already know this, please [edit] the question to indicate that you know {} is compatible with primitives.

The empty object type is a little weird at first.
So, first, typescript is structural. This means that {} describes a type that requires zero properties. Therefore, pretty much anything is assignable to {} because almost every type can fulfill the structural type contract that is having all zero of the required properties.

Second, as is inherently not type safe.
declare const strOrNull: string | null

const str: string = strOrNull as string // TS says fine, but really it might be null!
str.split(' ') // TS says fine, but maybe a crash

A type assertion using as tells Typescript that you know better than the compiler does, and you want to narrow the type that the compiler is using to something more specific that only you know it can be.
So given that that boolean is assignable to {} due to the first point above, it allows the type assertion.

Important lesson: Don't use as unless you are sure you are right.

For the record the below will also work:
let wow : {} = '2';
let wow2 : {} = 2;
let wow3 : {} = true;
let wow4 : {} = { a : 1};

All this is because TS has structural subtyping.
In structural subtyping, the type compatibility is based on structure. This is different from nominal subtyping where it has to be explcitiy defined.
Basically, the thing to remember for the above case is:

all fields should exit
extra fields are fine,
but incorrect fields (same field name with different type) are not.

For the above empty object type {}, the conditions do apply.
As added in the comments, the empty object will just accept anything, except null/undefined.
Related Github issues:
1
